# How to show child element dropdown above the parent's margin?

Tags: html, css

So my website screen looks like this:
[image]
As can be seen in the image above, my dropdown options are hidden behind the margin of the `<section>`. The original dropdown list height is shown in dotted line. I am using bootstrap dropdown here.

**How can I make the dropdown options to show above the margin of the parent.**

Here is the sample code for the dropdown:

```
<body>
   <section class="body" style="margin-bottom: 150px">
      <header class="header">...</header>
      <div class="inner-wrapper">
         <aside id="sidebar-left">...</aside>
         <section id="main-content" class="content-body">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <!-- dropdown code as shown below -->
               </div>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
   </section>
</body>
```

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown show" style="position: relative">
    <button class="multiselect-dropdown dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" style="position: relative">
        Dropdown
    </button>
    <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu show" x-placement="bottom-start">
        <li class="dropdown-item" tabindex="0">
            <label style="display: block;" class="checkbox" title="Option 1">
                <input type="checkbox" value="option_1">Option 1</input>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

Here is the css for the dropdown.

```
dropdown-menu.show {
    display: block;
}

.multiselect-container {
    max-height: 673px;                           # window height - 300
    overflow: hidden auto;
    position: absolute;
    will-change: transform;
    top: 0px;                                    # Calculated by popper.js which is used by bootstrap dropdown
    left: 0px;                                   # Calculated by popper.js which is used by bootstrap dropdown
    transform: translate3d(0px, -254px, 0px);    # Calculated by popper.js which is used by bootstrap dropdown
    z-index: 1000000,
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Pleas comment if anything else is required from my end.

Comment: can you please provide the full HTML of the page

Comment: Added the structure of the parents

Comment: still, it's not enough, code is not working, I don't know what libs you are using, I suggest you provide a working copy on codepen to stackblitz